# How do you create a TreeView template for grouping items with a HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate

So, I know how to create a TreeView, then add TreeViewItems and bind their ItemsSource and it makes it easy to show all the `OBJ`s that I have, but the problem I have is when people want to make groups of these items. How would I make a DataTemplate that will let me do the same as having my below `Data Warehouse`, but shown as a collection of user-selected items?

```
<TreeView.Items>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Data Warehouse">
        <TreeViewItem.Items>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Platforms">
                <TreeViewItem.Items>
                    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS, Converter={StaticResource COBJSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=Fixed}">
                        <TreeViewItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                Path=Parent.Items.Count,
                                StringFormat=Fixed Devices ({0})}">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS, Converter={StaticResource COBJSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=Mobile}">
                        <TreeViewItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                Path=Parent.Items.Count,
                                StringFormat=Mobile Devices ({0})}">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem.Items>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS, Converter={StaticResource CollectionSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=Public}" Header="Public" />
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS, Converter={StaticResource CollectionSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=Shared}" Header="Shared" />
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS, Converter={StaticResource CollectionSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=Private}" Header="Private" />
</TreeView.Items>
```

So, far I have the following:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityType:COLLECTIONS}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding COLLECTIONNAME}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

But this is where I get stuck, if I set the `ItemTemplate` with the `TreeViewItem`s then that will set `TreeViewItem`s for all *x* Items in the `ItemsSource` instead of having one set of `TreeViewItem`s then putting the individual Items into the proper TreeViewItem

Example of TreeView result:

- Data Warehouse <-- This will have entire inventory

  - Platforms

    - Fixed Devices (X)

      - Fixed Device A
      - Fixed Device B
    - Mobile Devices (X)

      - Mobile Device A
      - Mobile Device B
- Public <-- This directory is public holds created collection of user-selected devices

  - MyCollectionA <-- Holds "A" devices (All Devices in Collection A are in single List

    - Fixed Devices (1)

      - Fixed Device A
    - Mobile Devices (1)

      - Mobile Device A
  - MyCollectionB

    - Fixed Devices (1)

      - Fixed Device B
    - Mobile Devices (1)

      - Mobile Device B

As you can see, I want to have fixed locations for the different types, then have the individual items placed in the correct location.

Comment: Ever found a solution for this?